# how to optimise a view having derived tabels

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation , i have one view , whose structure is like following

```
select x.*,d.*

from x

left join (

select x, y,z,poleid from y -- and pivot is done here

) as d

on x.poleid=d.poleid

where x.country =1 




  I am calling it like so, select * from view1 where country=1
```

q1) I have seen the plan, it filters on table x but  it takes time in left join, because it gets whole data and then pivot it,

if i could put the filter y.country =1 in side,
then it would have been fast.

```
 but that can not be done as view does not take parameter.
```

so please suggest is there any way to speed up the view.

yours sincerely

Comment: Could you please publish full query source code and the associated execution plan as XML?

Comment: Can you put an index on the view for Country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps consider a TVF (Table-Valued Function)

**Example**

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[MyFuncName] (@country int)  
Returns Table
Return (
    Select x.*,d.*
     From  x
     Left Join (select x, y,z,poleid from y ) as d on x.poleid=d.poleid
     where x.country = @country
)
```

**Usage**

```
Select * From [dbo].[MyFuncName](1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to missing of important info regarding this question (full source code of query + estimated/actual execution plan) my best guess/solution is: I would move `JOIN predicate` inside of `PIVOT` source thus: instead of

```
select x.*,d.*

from x

left join (

select x, y,z,poleid from y -- and pivot is done here

) as d

on x.poleid=d.poleid -- <-- This predicate
...
```

I would use

```
select x.*,d.*

from x

outer apply (

select x, y,z,poleid 
from (
  select .... 
  from ...
  where x.poleid=d.poleid -- <-- This predicate
) AS a--lias
PIVOT ( .... ) -- and pivot is done here

) as d
...
```

Also, check if `d.poleid` column has an covering index thus:

```
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ INDEX ...
ON d -- replace alias with full table name
(poleid, ... other columns ? ...)
--INCLUDE (... covering columns ...)
```